# Почему выполняется функция если условия не действительное javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var localCount = 0;

    if(localCount === 0){
      $('html').mouseleave(function(){
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: '#openafter',
            },
            type: 'inline'
        });
        localCount++;
      });
    }
```

Условия ведь не действительно второй раз, но почему то попап открывается. Я проверяю через console.log. Значения для localCount всегда меняется

Comment: ну так проверка происходит только один раз, а дальше обработчик простоработает

Comment: Как можно это исправить?

Comment: перенести проверку внутри обработчика например

Answer (score 1):

Вот так будет верно:

```
var localCount = 0;

$('html').mouseleave(function(){
  if(localCount === 0){
    $.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {
          src: '#openafter',
      },
      type: 'inline'
    });
    localCount++;
  }
});
```

Ибо после этой строчки: `$('html').mouseleave(function(){`, вы указываете действия, которые будут выполняться при событии `mouseleave`, соответственно и условие, чтобы оно возымело эффект повторно, должно быть внутри функции-обработчика этого события.

Comment: Лучше, конечно использовать one.
```$('html').one('mouseleave', function(){
    $.magnificPopup.open({
      items: {
          src: '#openafter',
      },
      type: 'inline'
    });
});```